# Validate dates before conversion, aka. ISDATE() equivalent

Tags: sql, validation, datetime, db2, db2-luw

DB2 version is 9.7.0.7

I have a flat file, and need to validate fully prior to insert into a  production table.  For analysis, I've parsed it into a table where all columns are `VARCHAR`.

One of the tasks is to validate dates.  I need to be able to locate the specific invalid dates, to report on the scope (frequency) and solution (reason).

I use `ISDATE()` in Sybase and SQL Server, which returns a 1 for a valid date, and a 0 for an invalid date.  In Teradata, I left join to the `SYS_CALENDAR` table in the system catalog. It's been about 15 years since I've last been in a DB2 environment, but I believe analogs to either do not exist.
In this DB2 environment my role is limited to QA, meaning I cannot create T-SQL procedures or UDFs.

This thread is clever and makes me think there may be some Common Table Expression logic that could be employed in a query:
[ISDATE equivalent of DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510509/isdate-equivalent-of-db2/37054902#37054902)

That one falls short as a solution, however, because it only considers format - the presence of an invalid (but properly formatted) date like '2016-04-31' or '2016-02-30' will raise an error and the query will return no rows.

I need to return all rows, identifying if each is valid or invalid (or just return the invalid rows for investigation, even) - so doing a `CAST` or `CONVERT`, or inserting into a formatted table in a test environment won't work.

Is there an analog to `ISDATE()`, `SYS_CALENDAR`, or another solution that gets to the same end product of a row-wise presentation of dates that can't be cast to `DATE`, prior to performing that conversion/insert?

Comment: If you could determine a way to do this in a stored procedure, then the matter would be a "tools for the job" problem which you could take up with those paying you.

Comment: You can run a compound SQL statement (sometimes called an anonymous block) without creating a routine. So, yes, there is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `PureXML` extension as follows:

```
SELECT
 XMLCAST(XMLQUERY('string($D) castable as xs:date' PASSING mycolumn as D ) AS INT)
FROM 
 mytable
```

which will return 1 or 0.

Comment: Neat! I should probably point out that pureXML is not an extension, but a part of the DB2 query processing engine.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to have to read up on this - something new to learn!
Definitely looks simple and efficient - hopefully no penalty on performance - and I'm not currently sure how involved the DBMS is - if this is just presentation layer, or if could still raise a DBMS error?  I'll read up on it, thanks!

Comment: This mostly works, but the result displays this long string, rather than just "false" or "true" -
 
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" ?>false"

The prefix is unnecessary, but I can't find documentation that explains the string, or how to suppress it.  I could LOCATE and SUBSTR, but only if necessary.  Thanks!

Comment: The DB app I use does not show me the XML preamble. Try wrapping it inside `XMLCAST( ... AS CHAR)`

Comment: Works perfectly if I wrap it in an XMLCAST( ... AS VARCHAR(10)).  Solved - thanks!!